# Why String.split("$") doesn't work?

Tags: java, string, split

I have three part string with each part seperated by `$`  symbol
For example,

```
String s = "abc$efg$xyz";
```

Now when I split it using `split` method like this:

```
String values[] = s.split("$");
```

It `values` array contains that entire string as a single element.

But when I use this:

```
String values[]=s.split("\\$");
```

It perfectly works what I wanted meaning
now the `values` array contains `abc`,`efg` and `xyz` on index 0,1 and 2 respectively.

I was wondering why that first `split` didn't work as I used similar `split` when splitting on `a single white space` using `split(" ");`

Comment: why down vote I didn't knew much about regex so I asked here after searching any relevant question on SO?\

Comment: BTW `Pattern.quote("$")` is a safer escaping mechanism for regexes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the character `$` is a reserved token used in regular expressions to mark the end of a line. That's why you have to **escape it** using `\\`.

Answer (score 7):

`String.split` takes a regular expression.

`$` in a regex means the nd of the string, so you need to escape it if you want to match a literal `$` character.

Answer (score 0):

$ shown in your example is  in a regex means end of string  used in regular expression in java

it is used for

```
$   Checks if a line end follows
```

thus you hava to use  \\