# String Split in Java Giving Unexpected Results

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have a series of strings with the following format: "animal || type || area ||".

In Java, I'm trying to split the string so I can just the first part. Everything I have read online says to split the string:

```
String animalString = "animal || type || area"
String animalArray[] = animalString.split("||")

System.out.println("result = " + Arrays.toString(animalArray));
```

However, when I split the string it doesn't merely split based on the '||' division but instead splits every letter:

```
result = [a, n, i, m, a, l,  , |, |,  , t, y, p, e,  , |, |,  , a, r, e, a,  , |, |]
```

When I add a delimiter to the split method, it delimits the first part of the string, so that is not effective.

How can I split a string that has the above format so I can get the three words themselves in an array and not just the letters?

Comment: Try escaping the pipes `\|\|`.

Comment: tells me illegal escape character

Comment: `split` takes a regular expression, and `|` has a special meaning in regular expressions. In a string literal, you need to double the backslash (so `"\\|\\|"`)

Comment: Related, arguably a duplicate: [Split function doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644970/split-function-doesnt-work), [Why String.split("$") doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218504/why-string-split-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double escape them.  Once for the `String` and once for the `regex`. `\\` escapes the slash so it can be passed on to the regex as `\|` which escapes the `|`.

The `\\s*` allows for 0 or more white spaces before and after the `||`

```
String animalString = "animal || type || area";
String animalArray[] = animalString.split("\\s*\\|\\|\\s*");

System.out.println("result = " + Arrays.toString(animalArray));
```

prints

```
result = [animal, type, area]
```